# Images in the Twenty Fourteen theme

Tags: images, theme-twenty-fourteen

How and were do I change the size on the sticky post images and the other images in the theme twentyfourteen?

I would like 8 sticky post images on the "front page" instead of 6 and I want them in a more portrait format so that I can use all my old images on my current blog (600x850px). I like the theme but all my old images are not suitable for the format.

I really can't find the sizes anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

Well, that was... interesting. In a nutshell there seem to be two things in play here:

- `max_posts` set to `6` in `add_theme_support( 'featured-content'`
- `quantity` set to default `6` in `Featured_Content` class

`quantity` defines how many posts there are, but can be no larger than `max_posts`. However while result can be pushed *down* by changing `max_posts` it cannot be pushed *up* since there doesn't seem to be clean way provided for changing `quantity`. If I read code accurately it was either meant to be input in Customizer or was there and got removed.

So to change both, this is closest to sane I could come up with on Sunday evening:

```
add_action(
        'after_setup_theme',
        function () {
            add_theme_support(
                    'featured-content',
                    array(
                            'featured_content_filter' => 'twentyfourteen_get_featured_posts',
                            'max_posts'               => 8,
                    )
            );
        },
        11
);

add_filter(
        'option_featured-content',
        function ( $array ) {
            if ( ! empty( $array ) && is_array( $array ) ) {
                $array['quantity'] = 8;
            }

            return $array;
        }
);
```

Note that posts set is cached in transient, so need to re-save it with Customizer for new count to apply.

As for size - thumbnail size is used for grid version of it, see `content-featured-post.php`.

Answer (score 0):

The two image sizes are defined in the theme's `functions.php` file:

```
set_post_thumbnail_size( 672, 372, true );
add_image_size( 'twentyfourteen-full-width', 1038, 576, true );
```

Answer (score 0):

Add your own custom sizes or modify the values for the existing sizes.

You can use this code which includes a parameter to [`hard crop your images`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_image_size#Crop_Mode) in different positions:

```
add_image_size( 'custom-size', 220, 220, array( 'left', 'top' ) ); // Hard crop left top
```